# How to make use of Text to Speech in Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am a newbie to Windows Phone App Development. I am building a Windows Phone App where I want the App to greet the logged in user and also greet when logging out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the built-in Text-To-Speech engine. It doesn't even need to connect to internet.

You can try something like this:

```
var text2speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
await text2speech.SpeakTextAsync("Welcome to Text To Speech");
```

Hope it works. You can easily include this in a function and call it when the MainPage loads.

See more at: http://www.programfreaks.com/windowsphone/texttospeech.aspx

Comment: I am glad that I could be of some help.